# How do I write StoredProcedure sub-classes to call Oracle functions?

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc

I've written the following Spring JDBC API StoredProcedure sub-class:

```
class GetLdapPropertiesStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

protected GetLdapPropertiesStoredProcedure(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    super(jdbcTemplate, "get_ldap_properties");
    setFunction(true);
    declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("rs", new ProductPropertiesMapper()));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("in_ldap_code", Types.VARCHAR));
    compile();
}

public Properties execute(String productCode) {
    HashMap input = new HashMap();
    input.put("in_ldap_code", productCode);

    Map results = execute(input);

    Collection<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> entries = (Collection<Map.Entry<Object,Object>>) results.get("rs");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.entrySet().addAll(entries);
    return properties;
}

}
```

Which calls the following Oracle function:

```
FUNCTION get_ldap_properties (
in_ldap_code   IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN rowset;
```

However, when I call the above I get the following Oracle exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_LDAP_PROPERTIES'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can anyone please see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the statement you'll get for a function call (i.e. with `setFunction(true)) :`

```
{ ? = call get_ldap_properties(?) }
```

So you need to add a first out parameter for the return value. Try this instead:

```
setFunction(true);

// The return value parameter must be the first parameter that you declare.
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("RETURN_VALUE", OracleTypes.CURSOR, new ProductPropertiesMapper()));
```

Edit: Fixed the syntax to deal with the function's return value **and** the rowset when using Oracle according to Thomas Risberg's [answer](http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?p=231407) on Spring Community Forums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't tell me how to fix the rowset stuff. This answers the question:

http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?p=231407

Comment: There were 2 things here : adding a SqlOutParamater as **first** parameter and using the good Type. I don't know why I wrote Types.VARCHAR... I'll fix the answer.